# How to check if a CMD/BAT command line parameter matchs a specific word?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dos

H Hello, everyone. I intent to write a batch(umake.bat) file that does the following:

Check whether `-f` appears in one of bat parameters, so that I can take different actions in the .bat.

CASE 1:

User call

```
umake
```

Inside umake.bat I will execute

```
make -f Makefile.umk
```

CASE 2:

User call

```
umake debug=1 var="big cat"
```

Inside umake.bat I will execute

```
make debug=1 var="big cat" -f Makefile.umk
```

CASE 3:

User call

```
umake -f special.mk debug=1
```

Inside umake.bat I will execute

```
make -f special.mk debug=1
```

CASE 4:

User call

```
umake debug=1 -f
```

Inside umake.bat I will execute

```
make debug=1 -f
```

In case 4, make(GNU make) will not succeed because missing file name after `-f` . For simplicity, I don't have to care for this since it is user's fault and the problem will be reported by GNU make .

Summary:

- If user provide `-f xxx` in command parameter, I'll pass those parameter to `make` .
- If user does not provide `-f xxx`, I'll call `make` with all user's parameter as well as appending `-f Makefile.umk` as `make`'s extra parameters.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems to have found the solution, although the code is something verbose.

```
@echo off

set _F_MAKEFILE=-f Makefile.umk

:CHECK_PARAM_AGAIN
if "%~1" == "" (
  goto CHECK_PARAM_DONE
) else (
  if "%~1" == "-f" (
    set _F_MAKEFILE=
    goto CHECK_PARAM_DONE
  )
  rem echo @@@%1
  shift
)
goto CHECK_PARAM_AGAIN

:CHECK_PARAM_DONE

@echo on
make %* %_F_MAKEFILE%
```

NOTES:

- Using `%~1` is a must. Because: If `%1` has value `"big cat"`, `%~1` makes it `big cat` , so that we can surrond `%~1` with quotes.